# Left join коментариев к задаче

Tags: mysql

Возник один интересный вопрос. Есть две таблицы, Task и Comments.
Нужно присоединить в новое поле Comment к таблице Task. Поле Comment должно содержать массив комментариев к задаче.
Возможно ли сделать это в рамках одного запроса?
Сейчас делаю так:
MySQL

`select tasks.* , comments.comment, comments.atCreate

from tasks LEFT JOIN comments ON tasks.id = comments.tasks_id`

Но! На выходе получаю дубликаты (оно и логично), если у одной задачи несколько комментариев.
Очень нужен ваш совет как быть)

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: проблема в том, чтобы на выходе получилось ПОЛЕ вроде такого:
Comments:[{text:'какой-то текст',create:2019''}]

Comment: По-моему, Вы мыслите форматами PHP, хотя задаёте вопрос по MySQL... Добавьте в вопрос CREATE TABLE исходных таблиц, INSERT INTO примера наполнения, и покажите требуемый результат для именно этих данных (ещё лучше - сделайте fiddle и дайте ссылку).

Comment: Это очень долго все будет. Суть в том, что есть допустим Товар, и к нему коментарии. Сейчас я выбираю все, но получаются дубликаты. И возможно ли допустим каким-то способом объеденить дубликаты? 
Чтобы был 1 объект, а в нем поле с множество коментариев. Было бы круто, если поле было бы массивом. Не обязательно mysql

Comment: Ну так средства, указанные в самом первом комментарии, именно это и делают. Один таск, и к нему все каменты в CSV. Не нравится в CSV - добавь скобки, получится JSON array.